# changing textstream type in Qt

Tags: qt, encryption, codec

I have a small problem. i have written a code in Qt that will create an application which will take contents from a file encrypt it and save the encrypted contents to another file. now i have written another code as well which take contents from a file and decrypt and save the decrypted contents to another file. now when i did that my decryption results weren't correct. my algorithms are definitely correct. the problem is i guess with the text encoding format. because when i encrypted a particular text in another app and it displayed the encrypted contents in a lineEdit. i copied and pasted the same contents in a notepad file as unicode format. then i executed my decryption application. it gave me correct resulrs., so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your encryption create binary data from text data and is not just text only, you probably want to use a `QDataStream` for writing and reading the encrypted data, it handles writing chunks of bytes, e.g. `QByteArray` correctly without translation. If you used a `QTextStream` that probably won't work

Comment: thanks a lot. this was really helpful. it is almost working. but for one or two cases. which i will need to check the problem.